# Serving Compressed Files Amazon vs Lightty

Tags: amazon-ec2, lighttpd

We are currently using amazon CloudFront to serve css and according to Amazon itself, Amazon CloudFront can serve both compressed and uncompressed files from an origin server. But while i check compression it shows everything fine in origin server but it shows notcompressed checking in the link with cloudfront.

e.g.
http://www.port80software.com/tools/compresscheck.asp?url=http%3A%2F%2Fimgsrv.mydomain.com%2Fen-UK%2Fsomething.css

it would result with 
Compression status:     (gzip)

while with cloudfront

http://www.port80software.com/tools/compresscheck.asp?url=http%3A%2F%2hereisit.cloudfront.net%2F%2Fsomething.css

Compression status:     Uncompressed

Origin server is running lighttpd with mod_deflate however, allowed config is:

```
deflate.allowed_encodings      = ("bzip2", "gzip", "deflate")
```

[i would think, putting extra allowed encoding wont affect as such.]

Here i am clueless, what is the real issue.

Comment: [Reposted from Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39814/serving-compressed-files)